# Некорректное отображение модального окна на странице

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Пишу приложение на React, столкнулся с проблемой с модальным окном, её покажу на изображении:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У каждой карточки есть своё модальное окно. Когда кликаю на первую модалку первой карточки, остальные карточки выше положенного, а когда кликаю на последнюю карточку в списке - всё ок.
Код ниже

Компонент Card:
scss:

```
  .card {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 100px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
position: relative;
border: 1px solid black;
width: 277px;
height: 315px;
z-index: 1;
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 12%;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
font-family: 'Forum', cursive;



.pizzaImage {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 15px;
  left: 9%;
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.pizzaImage:hover{
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.info{
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top:10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.aboutPizza {
  display: flow;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #FEF6D1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 12%;
  margin-top: 110px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 204px;
  z-index: 2;


  .buttons {
    background-color: #FFC377;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  }

  button {
    background-color: transparent;
    font-size: 2.5vh;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    width: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .first {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    button {
      width: 33.3%;
    }
  }
  .second {
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    align-items: center;
    button {
      margin: 0;
      padding: -2px;
      font-size: 2.05vh ;
    }
  }
  h2 {
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
  }
}
```

}
}

jsx:

```
const Card = (props) => {
const [isOpened, setIsOpened] = useState(false);
return (
    <div className="card">
        <img className="info" src="/images/info.png" alt="info" onClick={() => setIsOpened(true)}/>
        <img className="pizzaImage" src= {props.image} alt="pizza" />
        <div className="aboutPizza">
            <h1>{props.title}</h1>
            <div className={"buttons"}>
                <form className="first">
                    <button>20 см</button>
                    <button>25 см</button>
                    <button>30 см</button>
                </form>
                <form className="second">
                    <button>Толстое тесто</button>
                    <button>Тонкое тесто</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <h2>{props.price} BYN</h2>
        </div>
        <Modal isOpened={isOpened} setIsOpened={setIsOpened}/>
    </div>
);
```

};

Модальное окно:
jsx:

```
const Modal = ({isOpened, setIsOpened}) => {
return (
    <div className={isOpened ? "modal" : "modal.active"} onClick={() => setIsOpened(false)}>
        <div className="modal__content" onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>

        </div>
    </div>
);
```

};

scss:

```
.modal {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

.modal.active {
  display: none;
}
.modal__content {
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  height: 500px;
  width: 700px;
}
}
```

Comment: У вас от z-index проблема, у модалки должен быть индекс больше. Я конечно вижу, что по коду он уже больше, но скорее всего вы чего то не договариваете, инспектируйте в браузере.

Comment: И еще, не имеет смысла писать подобное выражение "className={isOpened ? "modal" : "modal.active"}", вы можете сделать так {isOpened && <div><div>}

Comment: я новичок, можете посоветовать как инспектировать проект на реакте?

Comment: Запускаете проект, нажимаете f12 и смотрите по элементам что не так, прямо там можно редактировать стили